# blazor client application Cross-Origin Request Blocked: openid-configuration error

Tags: .net-core, blazor-client-side

Dotnet core 3.1 blazorwasm template app is giving the below error while accessing from network or after hosting it on a linux server. It seems the published app is always looking for local host ip for redirection at certain places.

the errors appeared on the firefox console is given bellow

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

how to configure and publish it to avoid routing to localhost.

This can be reproduced  by simply taking the code
https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop
after running it from visual studio try to access it from a remote client (another machine) will give error while navigating from login and registration links.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CORS middleware configuration to the web API's service's `Startup.Configure` method and see if that works:

```
app.UseCors(policy => policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5001")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType));
```

You need to add this to [this file](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/src/BlazingPizza.Server/Startup.cs) if you are using the code mentioned in your question.
Doc and sample project can be found [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors)